# blackberry webworks/phonegap push notfication not working

Tags: cordova, push-notification

I am trying to implement push notification for bb os 6 and 7 in my phonegap app I have put credientials received from blackberry team first time it give success,

after that shows err alert also i ma not receiving push notification on device .

I am using pushwoosh server to send notification please suggest what going wrong here is my code

```
var port = 33981; //THE_PORT_FROM_BB_REGISTRATION;
var serverUrl = "http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com";
var appId = "4223-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var max = 100;
var wakeUpPage = "index.html";

function openBISPushListener() {
    try {
        var ops = {port : port, appId : appId, serverUrl : serverUrl, wakeUpPage : wakeUpPage, maxQueueCap : max};
        //alert("obj = " + ops.wakeUpPage);
        alert(blackberry.push.openBISPushListener(ops, onData, onRegister, onSimChange));
    alert("success push");  
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Called openBISPushListener():Error - " + err);
        //alert(err);
    }    
}

function onRegister(status) {       
    alert("status" + status);
    if (status == 0) {      
        PushWoosh.register(function(data) {
                    alert("PushWoosh register success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                }, function(errorregistration) {
                    alert("Couldn't register with PushWoosh" +  errorregistration);
                });    
    }
    else if (status == 1) {
        alert("push register status network error");
    }
    else if (status == 2) {
        alert("push register status rejected by server");
    }
    else if (status == 3) {
        alert("push register status invalid parameters");
    }
    else if (status == -1) {
        alert("push register status general error");
    }
    else {
        alert("push register status unknown");
    }
}

function onData(data) { 

    alert("Push notifications received. Data is " + blackberry.utils.blobToString(data.payload));
    try {
        return 0; //indicate acceptance of payload for reliable push
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Called onData():Error - " + err);
    }
}

function onSimChange() {
    //handle Sim Card change
    alert("sim changed");
}
```

Comment: What status are you receiving? you should get status 0

Comment: first it shows alert 'undefined'  for code alert(blackberry.push.openBISPushListener(ops, onData, onRegister, onSimChange));  it shows 'err' in alert and then displays nothing when i close the app and reopen it then alert display as error in opening openBISPushListener()

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this myself as well. Two hurdles I've taken so far are:
 - You need blackberry internet services enabled  to be able to register the device (you can check: there should be a small blackberry icon next to the wifi icon in the status bar)
 - In the Pushwoosh settings, the PPG url needs to be HTTPS  instead of http like in the E-mail from blackberry

This has resulted in me being able to register devices and successfully send notifications from PushWoosh. (unfortunately still working on actually getting the notifications to arrive on my device)